# Sort button issueing new and unwanted API call for boostrap-vue table elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I'm developing in Vue2 using the 1 file = 1 component scheme.

Using a Bootstrap-Vue Table Component, I'm using the provider to pass it an items.

The issue is that when I use the sort button the sort one time out of a couple (if I press sort too fast) the sort fails because the API call for the list is called again and the list is displayed anew.

How would I correct this.

Do I need to design it another way?

my code :

```
<b-table small fixed bordered striped hover show-empty
             :no-provider-paging="true"
             :no-provider-sorting="false"
             :no-provider-filtering="true"
             :busy.sync="isBusy"
             :items="allergyIntolerance"
             :fields="fields"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :filter="filter"
             :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
             :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
             @filtered="onFiltered"
    >
      <template slot="identifiant" slot-scope="row">{{row.item.content._id}}</template>
      <template slot="patient" slot-scope="row">{{row.item.content.patient.reference}}</template>
      <template slot="practitioner" slot-scope="row">{{row.item.content.recorder.reference}}</template>
      <template slot="category" slot-scope="row">{{row.item.content.category}}</template>
      <template slot="status" slot-scope="row">{{row.item.content.clinicalStatus}}</template>
      <template slot="critical" slot-scope="row">{{row.item.content.criticality}}</template>
      <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" @click.stop="details(row.item,row.index,$event.target)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" @click.stop="edit(row.item,row.index,$event.target)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" @click.stop="del(row.item,row.index,$event.target)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      </button>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

note that if I pass `:no-provider-sorting` to true it no longer sorts.

every other option is working as intended.

```
allergyIntolerance (ctx) {
      var token = 'JWT eyJtokentokentokens'
      let promise = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/allergyintolerance/', {headers: { 'Authorization': token }})

      return promise.then(response => {
        const items = response.data.entry
        this.totalRows = items.length
        return (items)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
        return []
      })
    }
```

Comment: Show some code!

Comment: @AndreiNemes yes my bad :P here it is.

Comment: Perhaps you can set a bool to prevent doing a call to the API until the request has succeeded/failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend moving the data provision out of the table component itself. You may create a wrapper component which loads the table in a default state, fetches the data and updates the table on complete.
The table should otherwise be pretty dumb and not care about much else than rendering the data its given.

If you need a managed way to do this have a look at [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex), which also supports async actions.

Edit: I've attached a simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/z8eu0qz2/1/). It should be pretty straightforward to translate to your setup.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <my-container></my-container>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="my-table-template">
<div>
  <b-table
    :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
    :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
    :items="items"
    :fields="fields"
  >
  </b-table>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="my-container-template">
<my-table :items="items"></my-table>
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
Vue.component('my-table', {
  template: document.getElementById('my-table-template'),
  data() {
    return {
      sortBy: 'age',
      sortDesc: false,
      fields: [
        { key: 'last_name', sortable: true },
        { key: 'first_name', sortable: true },
        { key: 'age', sortable: true },
        { key: 'isActive', sortable: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  props: {
    items: Array
  }
})

Vue.component('my-container', {
  template: document.getElementById('my-container-template'),
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    // of course, there could be other events that would cause a data refresh
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      // you should use your real request instead of a timeout here
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.items = [
        { isActive: true,  age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true,  age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

As I said, it's a good idea to separate responsibility in your app broadly into components responsible for fetching and providing data (container components) and components that just render any data they are given, without any side-effects (presentational components).
You can think of container components' role as context providers - just consider how in the example above you can have more than one table (or varied other components) use the same data.

Comment: so abandon the bootstrap setup?

Comment: No, I mean fetch the data outside of the table and pass it in. The table should just render the current state of the data (and add interactivity) but should not be concerned with obtaining it. Local data transformations in the table, such as sort, should not require the data to be fetched again.

Comment: but my current component works according to the provider. I don't understand how I could accomplish this, could you provide an example?

Comment: I've attached an example in my answer. Also have a look at the reasoning at the bottom.